# Why does the run level change automatically?

Tags: init, runlevel

I am trying set up a virtual machine as an exercise for my friend, it came to my mind that I can give him a machine that reboots all the time and ask him to find out whats wrong with it. I change run level by `init 2` but it goes back to normal
How can I achieve my goal? and how would he be able to diagnose the problem?

Comment: With upstart "runlevels' are to a large extent depreciated. See http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#runlevels . You can sabotage a system in any number of methods.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I part of what I am looking for, any idea how would my friend be able to find the problem? also what are some other methods to sabotage the system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run level 2 is not reboot, in fact it is the normal run level. 6 is reboot. Also you generally want to use `telinit 6` not `init 6`. It is more portable between different unix implementations.

What you really want is an actual abstraction to just reboot the box though. I suggest using `reboot` instead of trying to understand runlevels.